# line height is not working correctly

Tags: html, css

**CSS**:
`span{line-height:25px;}`
**HTML**:
`<div><span>16<br>Fri.</span></div>`

However, the height of div is **49.6px** and line-height is 24.8px.
Only one computer has this situation.
Other height is 50px.
How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You fix it by using `display: inline-block`.

Inlined elements can't be sized. Consider it as simple text you can only color.

```css
span{
  line-height: 25px;  
}
```

```html
<div><span>16<br>Fri.</span></div>
```